# Calculating AVG() using Subquery in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
Select x.*, Avg(Columnz)as avg_columnz from
(
Select a,b,c,d,e,f,columnx-columny as columnz from table abc)x

group by a,b,c,d,e,f;
```

I am getting avg_columnz same as columnz

here is how ham getting rather than the actual average of columnz. What is it I am doing wrong here?

| a | b | c | d | e | f | columnx | columny | columnz | avg_columnz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that you really want to use `AVG()` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, columnx - columny AS columnz,
       AVG(columnx - columny) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c, d, e, f) avg_columnz
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY a, b, c, d, e, f;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick turn around but its still the Same, it was giving me the same value as columnz.